# I want to record sound in my app, in some devices it is working properly. But in Samsung Galaxy tab it is throwing the following exception

Tags: android

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.provider.MediaStore.RECORD_SOUND }

I'm using the following Code,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_RECORD_SOUND);
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the `Galaxy Tab` does not have any application that can handle your `Intent`. You should catch this `Exception` and show a proper `Dialog` to the user, or use `PackageManager` to check if there are any application that can handle the `Intent`, and again show a `Dialog`.

[`PackageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,flags)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you tell me how to use PackageManager to check if there is any application??

Comment: PackageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,flags); is showing error. Not works

Comment: "showing error"?. I can not provide you full code here. I am just giving you guidelines.

Comment: PackManager returning empty. Is there any other possibilities for this?

Comment: yes, it is returning empty because there is no app to `RECORD_AUDIO`. make a dialog an suggest to install such an app.. or something...

Comment: Is there any app available to record sound in such cases or shall we record using other third party tools?